# Does cocos2d or cocos3d need to buy any licence or it is a freeware?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm planning to develop an cocos2d or 3d iOS application, is this requires any license to buy or it is a freeware? Any help is thanks in advance.

Comment: just FYI, the second word on the homepage is "Free" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Licence is [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/license)

It says "Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software". You can use it without paying for anything.

Comment: ...but please don't forget: "The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software."

Comment: That's regarding source code distributions. Apps (binary distributions) do not have to include the license text in the app bundle nor is it necessary to display it in the app.

Comment: And it's always nice to include a little "made with cocos2d" somewhere in your app, just because of all the hard work the developers put into it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's a reasonable question, given the association with Zynga.  But don't worry because Cocos2D is currently released under the [MIT licence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License).  If Zynga ever tried to pull the plug, they can't do that retroactively, so people would just fork what was already there under the MIT licence and carry on.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/faq